# Member function mapping in python

Tags: python, class, member-functions

I have a class with many member functions, and I want self.func to have function pointer based on provided name. However, this way each class should have a dict from all names to functions which is clearly a waste. Is there a better way to do it? The issue with using class variable (instead of member variable) is that some of those functions depend on the information from the instance.

```
class C:
    def __init__(func_name):
        name_to_func = {"f1": self.func1, "f100": self.func2}
        self.func = name_to_func[func_name]

    def func1(self): return 1
    def func100(self): return self.a
```

Using following method needs a different usage (c = C("f1"); **c.func(c)**) instead of (c = C("f1"); **c.func()**):

```
    class C:
        name_to_func = {"f1": C.func1, "f100": C.func2}
    def __init__(func_name):
        self.func = name_to_func[func_name]
```

Comment: Make it a class variable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it"

Comment: The mapping, of course.

Comment: You mean like this: name_to_func = {"f1": C.func1, "f100": C.func2}, then they cannot be called like a member function and need passing of object

Comment: Right, so pass the instance? Or partially apply the instance  when you assign it to `self.func` And I mean define it as a class variable (i.e. static, not an instance variable).

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but would wrapping it with a lambda function to add self, cause some additional stack operations (nested functions)?

Comment: I mean, *that's exactly what happens anyway*.

Comment: I mean, you can literally just use `types.MethodType` which, again, is what happens underneath the hood to partially apply the instance to the function.

Comment: I think you are looking static variables of python. They exist only for the class and not for the instances.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python
explains the method quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables allow each Classes to have a single copy.

```py
import random


class C:
    def __init__(self, func_name):
        self.func = lambda :C.name_to_func[func_name](self)
        self.a = random.random()

    def func1(self):
        return 1
    def func100(self):
        return self.a
    name_to_func = {"f1": func1, "f100": func100}

x = C("f1")
y = C("f100")
assert(x.name_to_func is y.name_to_func)
x.func()
y.func()
```

Do note that because name_to_func now needs to run at class definition time, we need to ensure that each function is defined before it and it can access it.

Edit
I added the lambda to make it use an instance-specific variable. Is that what you were asking for.

Comment: The issue is that some of those functions depend on the information from the instance.

Comment: does other answer satisfy your requirements ?

Comment: @Roy can you give an example of your exact issue, because python is pretty dynamic and I don't see why the information from an instance cannot also be integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Every attribute in Python stored in dictionaries, so it's not a 'clearly' waste.

This is how every class is created in Python

> class name, inherited classes, attributes

```
type("", tuple(), dict())
```

so you can create classes or store your functions like that

```
def some_func(obj):
    return obj.attr

Foo = type(
     'Foo',
     (),
     {
         'attr': 100,
         'attr_val': lambda x : x.attr
         'my_func' : some_func
     }
)
```

Because of this implementation every attribute has `O(1)` time complexity

Check metaclasses from [here](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/)